# How to detect the launching of a javascript operation on uiWebView?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

How can I detect if the web page in uiWebView launch a javascript opération ? For exemple if the user click on a button managed with javascript (not a link), a function is started. How detect that ?

is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the delegate -

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Here navigationType may give wat u need..